# Run time error 1004: Method Offset of Object Range Failed in Loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is loop through Column A find the blank cells and copy the two numbers in column B and C of that row in the row above after the last cells in the row. Then delete the row with the blank in column A.

Here is an image of the blank cell before the code is executed:
[image: Here is an image of the blank cell before the numbers were copied]

And the second image shows the result of my code:
[image: And the second image shows the result of my code]

```
Sub PivotTableLayout()

Dim rng As Range
'Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CopyPivot").Columns("A")
For Each cell In rng.Rows
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        ' Do while is blank
        Do While IsEmpty(cell)
            'offset one right and copy two cells
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Copy
            ' offset counter and 1 up
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
         Loop
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

However, I keep receiving runtime error 1004 on this line, but it works if I remove it from the code...I cant figure out why:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

Comment: Replace all references to `ActiveCell` with `cell`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you! that worked, however, now my code is not doing what I would like it to. If there are multiple blanks one after the other it only does the copy paste for the first blank and then skips the rest of the blanks. Is a Do while loop not appropriate to use here?

Comment: Avoid the use activeCell or start in the correct place.
The replace of activeCell for cell seems the correct, but have a problem ... you can see that the following cell in the loop after delete puts cell in a strange state and crash your algorithm in the following empty cell.
The best way is to work directly with the cells in the workbook and avoid
Set rng = ...
When delete cells inside the range.
@Mrig has made a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are deleting **rows** (or columns) its always better to loop from **bottom to top** (or right to left). Following code will give you the desired result.

```
Sub PivotTableLayout()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            lastColumn = Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Range("B" & i, Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
**___________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub PivotTableLayout2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            lastColumn = Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Mrig, this produces an error on: 
    lastColumn = Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Run time error 1004: Method "_Default" or object range failed.

Any idea why?

Comment: I have tested and worked, maybe put in the beggining of the code

Sheets("CopyPivot").Select

Just to prevent the active sheet is the correct

Comment: @erikasoladams - Is there any row with no data at all i.e. completely blank row?

Comment: @Mrig yes I took it out...okay now it works for the majority of the sheet. Whats really weird is that is doesnt work for cell A4 and A24...then it runs through the whole sheet and executes properly. Once it is done executing I get another error 1004: Method copy of object range failed

Comment: @erikasoladams - Will be hard to reproduce the state where its not working for A4 and A24. If you can share your sheet I can look into it.

Comment: @Mrig okay, Thank you! how do I share my sheet with you? is there an email I can send it too?

Comment: @erikasoladams - You can upload your file online and share the link here.

Comment: @Mrig https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4IDjPo77GOpbzNObndFVlVkV1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @erikasoladams - Instead of this `Range("B" & i, Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)` write `Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)`

Comment: @erikasoladams - See my edit in answer, should work fast.

Comment: why not push the rows to delete in a variable and delete them later in one step? this would be faster + you could run the the loop forwards.

Comment: @DirkReichel - Yeah, that surely will be faster. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Mrig Hi Mrig, Slight change again...now I just want to copy one cell that is the last column on the line that is blank. I tried changing the code from this: 
`Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)` 

To this:
`Range(Cells(i, "D")).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)`

Without any success...

Comment: @erikasoladams - To copy cell at the last column in a blank row write: `Cells(i, Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)`

Comment: @Mrig Thank you! almost there! the only issue is that it only copies two registrations per person. The registrations are overwritten if there are 3 and higher and never writes to column F. There must be something wrong with the lastcolumn variable.

Comment: @Mrig in case you see this later...all is working! thank you so much for your help

Comment: @erikasoladams - `never writes to column F` is this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the function specialcells:

```
Sub remove()
    Dim rFirstColumn As Range
        Set rFirstColumn = Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
    Dim rBlanks As Range
        Set rBlanks = rFirstColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Dim iBlanks As Integer
        iBlanks = rBlanks.Count
    Dim iCount As Integer

    For iCount = 1 To iBlanks Step -1
        Set rPrevious = rBlanks.Cells(iCount, 1).Offset(-1, Columns.Count - 1).End(xlToLeft)
        Range("B" & rBlanks.Cells(iCount, 1).Row, Range("B" & rBlanks.Cells(iCount, 1).Row).End(xlToRight)).Copy rPrevious.Offset(0, 1)
        Rows(rBlanks.Cells(iCount, 1).Row).Delete
    Next iCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two lines of the @Mrig solution, and solve some details. This solution only see the empty cells.

```
'more efficient ...just work with empty cells
    Sub PivotTableLayout3()
        Dim i As Long
        Dim aux As Object
        Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
        Sheets("CopyPivot").Select
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        i = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1 'first empty cell
        While (i < lastRow)
            While IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) And i < lastRow 'working with empty cells
                Set aux = Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight)
                If Not aux.Column = 16384 Then 'not empty row
                    lastColumn = Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Range("B" & i, Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy Cells(i - 1, lastColumn + 1)
                End If
                Rows(i).Delete
                lastRow = lastRow - 1 'my last row has changed
            Wend
            i = Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1 'next empty cell
        Wend
    End Sub
```